# Account linking fails on my google smart home service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, auth0, google-smart-home

The service hosted on cloud function was running fine for past 1.5 years and recently started bugging out.

The problem was found while signing into my google service through auth0 SPA.
After a successful login the app leaves a "Service failed to link please try again later"

I checked the Auth0 keys and callback urls which seem to be working fine. Also tested the cloud functions and came across this piece of error in cloud logs explorer.

```
{
insertId: "1o8jhsx8be"
jsonPayload: {
syncLog: {
syncs: [
0: {
httpLatencyMsec: "6580"
requestId: "10830040163618754695"
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}]}}
logName: "projects/deft-d3e/logs/assistant_smarthome%2Fassistant_smarthome_logs"
receiveTimestamp: "2022-12-02T11:45:35.964382849Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2022-12-02T11:45:35.964382849Z"
}
```

How do I proceed further to know where is this going wrong ?

I tried updating the npm packages to my project and the node version but it didnt seem to have any changes

Comment: Can you provide more logs to see which part is failing ? From the logs that you have shared it might be Step 3 of the account linking process. 
Can you also provide detailed requests and response logs, for the error showing “Invalid Arguments”.

Answer (score 0):

Access and Refresh Tokens for an OAuth system might expire over time, and your system might have an issue to renew these.
In general, there are three steps to complete account linking :

--Initiate linking and login to get OAuth code.
--Exchange OAuth code with tokens.
--Use token to sync the devices.

If your Smart Home integration has been working over the past 1.5 years, but started to fail recently for Account Linking, the most likely culprit is the tokens you issue. You can learn more about [Account Linking](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/primer/account-linking) through our documentation site.